# Multiple Timer in containerView swift 4 xcode

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, nstimer, countdowntimer

I have one main ControllerView with two container view on top of each other (containerA on top of ContainerB). both containerView has a ControllerView.
I am running a timer in each ContainerView. problem I am facing is that when I hide ContainerB to show ContainerA, the timer of containerB still running in the background, which is causing over 100% CPU use.

can any please help me how to stop the timer when I have other containerView visible?
I am using two buttons to hide and show the container views.

ContainerA timer code:

```
ViewATimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self,   selector: (#selector(self.update)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

container B:

```
ViewBTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10, target: self,   selector: (#selector(self.secondUpdate)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you show ContainerA  do

```
ViewBTimer.invalidate()

ViewATimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(self.update)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

//

When you show ContainerB do

```
ViewATimer.invalidate()

ViewBTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10, target: self,   selector: (#selector(self.secondUpdate)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: I tried that, but no lock...both timer still runs in the background.

Answer (score -1):

To stop the timer

```
func stopTimer(timer: Timer) {
 if timer != nil {
    timer.invalidate()
    timer = nil
 }
}
```